Google Sheets - Finding the average cost of current holding in stocks
I've been at this for i don't know how long, and can't seem to find a formula that can automatically calculate the average cost for my current holding in a stock.
I currently have a setup where i insert the data, like seen in the first screenshot below, and then press the arrow for it to be moved by some JavaScript, as a new row, to another sheet, seen in the second screenshot. As i insert it, i have two main actions. Buy and Sell. (The screenshots are just exampels)
Screenshot 1
Screenshot 2
I need one, (Or more if needed), formula that can calculate the average price cost for the shares i have left, and for it to update itself as i insert more rows with either buying or selling.
Hope this makes sense. Otherwise feel free to ask if i am missing any information.
I have already tried some formulas and asking some AI, but none of it has seemed to work.

Getting Average Price based on Amount Paid and Action Buy/Sell
I would like to start this answer by setting your expectation that this is what I have understood for your question. You can comment in case that you need adjustment or I misunderstood your expected results.
Try this:
={{"Average Price",(MINUS(sumif(C2:C,"Buy",E2:E),(sumif(C2:C,"SELL",E2:E))))/(MINUS(sumif(C2:C,"BUY",D2:D),(sumif(C2:C,"SELL",D2:D))))};{"Current Stock",MINUS(sumif(C2:C,"BUY",D2:D),(sumif(C2:C,"SELL",D2:D)))}}

Note: Please paste this formula on the part where it is not going to be affected by your dataset. I tried to simplify the data as possible for my example to be readable
Sample Result:

Reference:
Sumif
Minus

I see where you are coming from. But the average price can't be so low, when you've paid, in your exampel, 32 Per share. And another with 100 Per share. In that case the average will at least be above 32, and therefore can't be 17

I understand your concern about the formula, I do apologize I failed to double check what I have pasted as an image along with my answer let me edit it.

I think i found a solution, that seems to work:
=((SUMIFS(F:F, B:B, "NKE", C:C, "Buy"))/(SUMIFS(D:D, B:B, "NKE", C:C, "Buy")))*(SUMIFS(D:D, B:B, "NKE", C:C, "Buy") - SUMIFS(D:D, B:B, "NKE", C:C, "Sell"))
I might have made it harder than it really was, but this seems to get the correct average price for all the shares i have of a stock like NKE. If you want the individual average price per share, you have to simply remove the end of the formula, so it only says:
=((SUMIFS(F:F, B:B, "NKE", C:C, "Buy"))/(SUMIFS(D:D, B:B, "NKE", C:C, "Buy")))

It is great to hear that you have found your answers.
